# SpringBoot-- I can't get message in the console logged in ApplicationListener that interested in ApplicationStartedEvent

Tags: spring-boot

I can't get message in the console logged in `ApplicationListener` that interested in `ApplicationStartedEvent`. I have find the reason. But I don't understand why spring does it like that. I find there is a `LoggingApplicationListener` in which called `this.loggingSystem.beforeInitialize()`.In `beforeInitialize()` a `turboFilter` has been added into `logback`,the `turboFilter` return a deny in his `decide()`.

I  know a little english , please help me

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot fires some events very early, before the `ApplicationContext` is even created or the `LoggingSystem` is initialized. The reason for the latter is that you can configure logging using keys from `application.properties`.

Spring Boot needs to read the `Environment` first and then use those keys to let the logging system configures itself. During that period, no logging is enabled so if you use it in your own listener, nothing will happen.

We [gave a university session last November](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uof5h-j0IeE) on those topics and there is a [section on application events](https://youtu.be/uof5h-j0IeE?t=1h26m4s).

Careful with `ApplicationStartedEvent`. The name is misleading, it's actually the very first event we fire (we should have named this `ApplicationStartingEvent` and [we've done that recently](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7381)). If you want to check that the application has (fully) started, you may want to use `ApplicationReadyEvent`. The logging system is initialized at that point so you can safely use loggers.